# Регулярные выражения.Удаление символов в начале и конце строки

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

пытаюсь удалить символы в строке (£0.78)
Вот таким регулярным выражением [\W].
но проблема в том, что данное регулярное выражение уберет скобки, значок валюты и точку по середине, а мне нужно число с плавающей точкой из данной строки, как бы я мог реализовать это по правильному?
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: У вас строка какой длины? `(£0.78)` в ней содержится, или это и есть строка? Причём тут начало и конец строки? Удаление символов из начала и конца делается с помощью `s.substring(1,s.length()-1)`.

Comment: Это и есть вся строка, мне нужно было удалить первый символ скобки, символ валюты и последний символ закрывающей скобки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте поиск:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?");
Matcher m = p.matcher("(£0.78) а также ($1.78)");
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group());
}
// => 0.78, 1.78
```

[Пример работы программы](https://ideone.com/6nIOio)

Если нужно только первое (или одно) совпадение, замените `while` на `if`.

**Подробности**

- `\d+` - 1 и более цифр
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - 1 или 0 повторов

  - `\.` - точка
  - `\d+` - 1 и более цифр

Comment: Большое спасибо, ваш ответ был самым полезным.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("(£0.78)".replaceAll("[^\\d.£]",""));
```

или

```
System.out.println("(£0.78)".replaceAll("[()]",""));
```

Comment: Спасибо! Хороший вариант, но в строке постоянно меняется валюта, но этот ответи был полезен для меня.

Comment: Если удалять нужно всегда только первый и последний элемент, используйте `s.substring(1,s.length()-1)`, как я и писал ранее.